# The VueRouter is not willing to substitute the `router-view` tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-router, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to integrate the VueRouter into my small application, but I end up with the `router-view` tag replaced with a comment.

Perhaps, it is because of HtmlWebpackPlugin.

Sorry for the huge listings, but I think every detail is important.

main.js:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import PumpView from "./PumpView.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: "/", component: PumpView },
    ],
});

new Vue({
    router,
}).$mount("#app");
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

PumpView.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="pump-view">
        <chart-mini-grid></chart-mini-grid>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
.pump-view {
    height: inherit;
}
</style>

<script>
import ChartMiniGrid from "./ChartMiniGrid.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        ChartMiniGrid,
    },
};
</script>
```

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require("vue-loader/lib/plugin");

module.exports = function () {
    return {
        target: "web",
        mode: "production",
        entry: {
            main: "./src/main.js",
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: "vue-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: "ts-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        "vue-style-loader",
                        "css-loader"
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
        },
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: "single",
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: "all",
                maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
                minSize: 0,
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name (module) {
                            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
                            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin({
                cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: [
                    path.join(__dirname, "src/lightweight-charts/dist"),
                ],
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                PRODUCTION: true,
            }),
            new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: "Geralt",
                filename: "index.html",
                template: "src/index.html",
                favicon: "src/assets/favicon.png",
            }),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        ],
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "[contentHash].js",
            chunkFilename: "[name].[contentHash].js",
            publicPath: "/",
        },
    };
};
```

I have been trying to mess around the stuff for a few hours, including removing the HtmlWebpackPlugin and putting the HTML template into the `Vue` object constructor:

```js
new Vue({
    router,
    template: `<html>...</html>`,
}).$mount("#app");
```

Now I don't know what else I can try.

I suspect some stuff in my Webpack config is conflicting with the idiomatic VueRouter configuration.

My `PumpView` component is not broken, as everything works like a charm if I add the render function beside the router field:

```js
new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(PumpView),
}).$mount("#app");
```

P.S. I am not using webpack-dev-server, but building with the production config, so it is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need the App.vue, the container which include the router-view

```
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

then, use it when initialize the Vue

```
import App from './App.vue'
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Because the router-view is the Vue component, you shouldn't use it in the outer html

Comment: Can I use the `App.vue` template from the main `HtmlWebpackPlugin` one?
Why don't VueRouter manuals include `render: h => h(App)`?

Comment: No, `HtmlWebpackPlugin` is the plugin for process the html. `router-view` is the `vue-component` like the `PumpView  Component` you've written.

Comment: `vue-router` is the router which exports the `router-view component`, `render` is the `vue` options, so they have their own duties. Besides `render options` , you can also use the `template options`, it is totally up to you

Comment: Where do you put the `app` id for the `$mount` function?
It seems the render function always replaces my `<div id="app"></div>` element, so `router-view` disappears.
If I remove the render function, I have no place to put my `App` component.

Comment: You can put the `app` id in the `$mount('#app')`, this means `<div id="app"></div>` will be replaced by the `render functions`.
`<div id="app"></div>` in the html is just the container for `vue render`

Comment: Thanks! With your help I managed to make it work with HtmlWebpackPlugin.